# VS Code with Xdebug when the open project window is not at the root of the application

Tags: xdebug, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to use Xdebug in VS Code, but the VS Code window I have open is not the root of the application. And in this scenario Xdebug isn't working: breakpoints are ignored as if I wasn't running the debugger at all.

Here's the situation:

```
myproject <- this is the app root.
- repos
-- drupal <- I have this folder open in xdebug
```

If I open a VS Code window at `myproject` and run Xdebug there, then it works as expected. But I prefer to open in a subfolder for simplicity.

I've tried setting `"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/../.."` in launch.json but that didn't work.

Comment: It sounds like the debug may be starting at the file that is outside of the project. Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see the log -- what entry file will be there. Is it inside the "simplified project" or not.

Comment: The starting file is definitely outside my simplified project, as it's vendor/bin/phpunit in my current case.

Comment: If it's outside ... then VSCode can see it like this: "I have no idea what the file is. How can I work with it?". I'm not using VSCode myself (another IDE user) so cannot say if VSCode can workaround this in some way. But you definitely need to look into some "path mappings" config (if it's present). For me personally, the current behaviour is expected and makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have no idea how it works, so I was thinking VS Code got told about each file that's reached during execution.